Where is the error in evaluating this integral? $\int^1_0\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{x\ln(x)}{(1-x)^2} dx$
Where is the error in evaluating this integral? $$I=\int^1_0\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{x\ln(x)}{(1-x)^2} dx$$
we have :
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$$
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}$$
Therfore:
$$I=\int^1_0\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n+nx^n\ln(x) dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int^1_0x^n+nx^n\ln(x)dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
But using wolfram alpha :
$$I=-1+\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

How do you justify the swap of $\sum$ and $\int$?

The summation here $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}$ should start at 1.

A slightly different approach with a few preparatory steps:
recall that for $|t|<1$: $$-\ln\left(1-t\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{j}}{j}$$ Notice that for $|t|<1$:
$$
\frac{1}{t^{2}}\left(t-(1-t)\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{j}}{j}\right)=\frac{1}{t^{2}}\left(-t+t+\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{t^{j}}{j-1}-\frac{t^{j}}{j}\right)\right)=\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\frac{t^{j-2}}{j\left(j-1\right)}
$$and
for the boundary: $t-\left(1-t\right)\ln\left(1-t\right)\to1$ as $t\to1$ $$\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j\left(j-1\right)}=\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(j-1\right)}-\frac{1}{j}=1$$. So we have no problem with the boundary of the convergence radius - this holds for $t=1$, too.
Set $t=1-x$:
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-x)+x\ln x}{(1-x)^{2}}\mathsf{d}x=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-t)\cdot\ln(1-t)+t}{t^{2}}\mathsf{d}t=
$$
$$
=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\frac{t^{j-2}}{j\left(j-1\right)}\mathsf{d}t=\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{j-2}}{j\left(j-1\right)}\mathsf{d}t=\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j\left(j-1\right)^{2}}=
$$
$$
=\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(j-1\right)^{2}}-\frac{1}{j\left(j-1\right)}=\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}-1
$$

Very nice (+1)! You start with "A slighty different approach". I suggest to make clearer (for OP and the readers) what is the difference and why it works: you use a convergent (also at $x=1$) series for the log and you never split the integrand (conserving convergence), whereas OP split the problem into an addition of two diverging integrals and used series for $1/(1-x)$ and $1/(1-x)^2$ respectively, which diverge at $x=1$. Hence addition of both divergent series representations for the two integrals (one with positive, one negative result) produced a pseudo-converging result which is wrong.

What you are trying to do is to split the task into  two separate integrations $\int^1_0\frac{1}{1-x}dx$ and $\int^1_0 \frac{x\ln(x)}{(1-x)^2} dx$ which both diverge. So you generally cannot replace the two integrands in these separate integrations with infinite sum expansions and exchange sums and integrals.
Here is a correct treatment in your vein: Compute
$$
\lim_{y\to 1^- }\int^y_0\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{x\ln(x)}{(1-x)^2} dx
$$
where you do NOT exchange limit and integration. The separate integrals converge, so you can follow your steps until
$$
I(y) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int^y_0x^n+nx^n\ln(x)dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{y^{n + 1}}{(n + 1)^2} + \frac{ n \ln(y) y^{n + 1} }{n + 1} 
$$
Whereas the first part of this gives indeed
$$
\lim_{y \to 1^- } \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{y^{n + 1}}{(n + 1)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} \quad ,
$$
the second part is
$$
\lim_{y \to 1^- } \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{ n \ln(y) y^{n + 1} }{n + 1} = \lim_{y \to 1^- } \frac{ - y \ln(y)}{y - 1} + \ln(1 - y)\ln(y)= -1 \quad .
$$
Notice in the second part that when performing the prohibited (!) exchange of summation and limit, we had
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \lim_{y \to 1^- } \frac{ n \ln(y) y^{n + 1} }{n + 1} =
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 0 = 0
$$
which is wrong. In total,
$$
I = \lim_{y \to 1^- } I(y) = - 1 + \frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$

That's not the Cauchy Principal Value. It's an improper integral, but those are not the same thing.

@jjagmath It’s actually not even an improper integral. The integrand as a whole is bounded at the singularities, and so they are removable.

@DavidH Oh, you're right, it's not even improper.

You're right. However, what OP tries to do is to replace the original integration with two divergent integrations, so the rest of his treatment won't be guaranteed to work. I edited my text accordingly.
